# Reconciling Lindley's paradox: Why would a frequentist choose a seq. of significance levels?

Tags: statistical-significance, bayesian, frequentist

In this [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindley%27s_paradox) about the Jeffreys-Lindley's paradox, in the subsection «Reconciling the Bayesian and frequentist approaches», right in the first sentence, it's written « if we take a sequence of significance levels, $\alpha_n$». Why would a frequentist take such a sequence? Shouldn't the significance level be determined right at start, with a fixed level?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The operative word in that quotation is the initial "if": it is not asserting that anyone would necessarily proceed in that fashion.

Comment: [Lindley's paradox](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5973) relies on the fact that the $t$ statistic that appears in both the frequentist and the Bayesian answers is kept fixed. Why would this statistic remain fixed for all $n$?

Comment: @Xi'an the wikipedia link talks about the significance level, not the statistic... I don't understand the relevance. I'm new to this.

Comment: @whuber yes, but If it's there, there has to be some motivation for it, I would think. Or is that subsection completely tangential to the main topic of that page? 
Could you please give some sort of motivation behind it which would make a statistician adopt it?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. The link is to a paper I wrote on Lindley's paradox a little while ago.

Comment: @Xi'an yes, I had noticed that. I had already found that paper. However, I was trying to avoid having to read the 15 pages just for this. Not trying, nor wanting, to be disrespectful, but I'm trying to read "The Bayesian Choice", and sometimes it seems more complex than it could be (for me). So, I thought that the paper would have the same level of complexity. I guess I'll have to try... ;)

Comment: In short, the conflict between frequentist and Bayesian solutions to the point null test arises because the argument considers the $t$ statistic as fixed and makes the rhetoric move that this keeps the frequentist conclusion fixed (while the Bayesian solution happily drifts to infinity!). This is not necessarily true if the level $\alpha_n$ decreases with $n$.

Comment: The respective section of the Wikipedia article is poorly written. I partially edited it (before stumbling upon this question) clarifying what I can – which is admittedly not much.